# Choose which calendar event goes into using Google Calendar Quick Add

Tags: google, google-calendar

Is there any way to specify which calendar the event should be put in when adding an event using Quick Add in Google Calendar.

The [help article](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=36604#text) on the topic gives all sorts of advanced options, but I can't seem to find one to select which calendar to add the event to.

Am I being stupid, or is there no way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can't select which calendar in Quick Add. However if you add event by clicking on your calender grid, you can bring up a dialog which allows you to select your calendar. That's pretty quick to me too. E.g. I can say "@7am dentist appt", then select a calendar, then submit, this doesn't go through the full calendar configuration screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Windows user, this free tool allows you to specify the calendar:
[Google Calendar Quick Add Utility for Windows](http://mountwhite.net/en/google%C2%AD-cal%C2%AD-quick-%C2%ADadd-%C2%ADsoftware.html)

Answer (score -1):

I just solved this in Fantastical. It doesn't seem to work in Google Calendar. One of my calendars is "commitments". I typed "movie 5:00pm calendar com" and it selects the right calendar.

Comment: The question is about using Google Calendar, not Fantastical.